# Trigger updating multiple records in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```
CREATE  TABLE `accounting`.`People` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `Property_number` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `People_at_Location` INT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );

INSERT INTO `accounting`.`People` (`Name`, `Property_number`, `People_at_Location`) VALUES ('Jim', '13', '2');
INSERT INTO `accounting`.`People` (`Name`, `Property_number`) VALUES ('Tony', '16');
INSERT INTO `accounting`.`People` (`Name`, `Property_number`) VALUES ('Alice', '9');
INSERT INTO `accounting`.`People` (`Name`, `Property_number`, `People_at_Location`) VALUES ('Martha', '13', '2');
INSERT INTO `accounting`.`People` (`Name`, `Property_number`) VALUES ('Vandy', '');
```

In our data we know the name for each and every row/record.  But when we started we did not have Property_number.    As we receive an email back from our clients we get their Property_number, and we update the record.

What we really need is a Trigger that looks at the Property_number and queries to see how many other records in the database have the same property number and updates all the records as we now know an additional person is at that Property_number.

For example  (given the sample data above) it look like:

```
ID     Name     Property_number     People_at_location
1      Jim      13                  2
2      Tony     16                  Null
3      Alice    9                   1
4      Martha   13                  2
5      Vandy    Null                Null
```

So we get new information from Vandy that tells us she is in property_number 13.  We want to update record 1, 4 and 5 to reflect the updated People_at_location count.

```
ID     Name     Property_number     People_at_location
1      Jim      13                  3
2      Tony     16                  Null
3      Alice    9                   1
4      Martha   13                  3
5      Vandy    13                  3
```

What would this trigger look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general form would be something like this (done from memory so there might be a few syntax mistakes):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_people_at_location
    AFTER UPDATE ON People FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
        // make sure we updated the property number from a NULL value to a non null
        // depending on your exact use case you may or may not want that check
        IF (OLD.Property_number IS NULL AND NEW.Property_number IS NOT NULL) THEN
           -- store the count for this property_number
           -- we are in an AFTER UPDATE trigger so the update is already done,
           --   which means this count will include the newly set value
           DECLARE total_people_at_location int;
           SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_people_at_location FROM People WHERE Property_number = NEW.Propery_number;
           -- update the rows with the proper count
           UPDATE People SET People_at_location = total_people_at_location WHERE Property_number = NEW.Propery_number;
        END IF;
    END
```

This should also work fine with records who have their current count at `NULL` (like ID 2 in your exemple), although these records are obviously wrong in your current state of data (I see no reason why you have a non `NULL` `Property_number` but a `NULL` `People_at_location`, that makes no sense);

i suppose that you probably want to do the same calculation on an insert of a new record, in which case you should extract the logic to a stored procedure, and call that procedure during the trigger instead of duplicating code.

Comment: It's quiet surprising, that this answer is marked as accepted. If you just give it a try (after correcting minor mistakes), you should (and you will) obviously get a "#1442 - Can't update table 'People' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger." error.